# Reorder and add content to Strings

Tags: python, string

Im a Newbie in Coding and Python. There is a thing, and I cant find a satisfied answer by google: I got a STRING and would like to reorder and add some to its content:

EXAMPLE:

Content of the STRING (some coordinates to Draw a SVG-grafic):

STRING
`M xy(1) xy(2) xy(3)   C(1) xy(4) xy(5) xy(6)   C(2) xy(7) xy(8) xy(9)`

I'd like to change this into this automatically:
(copy a value to the front vor 'M', and set a new 'C' after, to the first 3 pairs)

STRING_new
`M xy(9)   C3 xy(1) xy(2) xy(3)   C(1) xy(4) xy(5) xy(6)   C(2) xy(7) xy(8) xy(9)`

At least i'd like to return String_new

I guess there are complicated operations to do that, but for sure I am a Newbie

So how to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the simplest way is to separate all elements in the initial string, and then to concatenate them.

For example:

```
string = 'M xy(1) xy(2) xy(3) C(1) xy(4) xy(5) xy(6) C(2) xy(7) xy(8) xy(9)'
list_element = string.split(' ')
new_string = '{0} {11}   C3 {1} {2} {3}   {4} {5} {6} {7}   {8} {9} {10} {11}'.format(*list_element)
```

will result in :

```
>>> new_string
'M xy(9)   C3 xy(1) xy(2) xy(3)   C(1) xy(4) xy(5) xy(6)   C(2) xy(7) xy(8) xy(9)'
```

But this is not a very flexible solution, since all will be wrong if your input change.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you ask, but is the C3 in the result supposed to be C(3)?

```
"""
Given a string like s, convert it so that the value after the initial m is replaced by the last value in the string.
This is followed by a new C tag (incremented over the final original C tag), and the rest of the original string 
beyond the M start tag is appended

s =     "M xy(1) xy(2) xy(3) C(1) xy(4) xy(5) xy(6) C(2) xy(7) xy(8) xy(9)"
new_s = "M xy(9) C3 xy(1) xy(2) xy(3) C(1) xy(4) xy(5) xy(6) C(2) xy(7) xy(8) xy(9)"
"""

import re


s =     "M xy(1) xy(2) xy(3) C(1) xy(4) xy(5) xy(6) C(2) xy(7) xy(8) xy(9)"

last_c = re.findall(r'C\((\d+)\)', s)[-1]
new_c = "C%s" % str(int(last_c) + 1)
my_list = s.split()
new_start = " ".join((my_list[0], my_list[-1]))
new_s = " ".join((new_start, new_c, s[1:]))
print new_s
```